# Adjusting product listing dynamically with a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I have created a WordPress WooCommerce plugin selling products as fundraisers. The administrator creates a "sale" which includes an organization and a list of affiliates (salesmen). A user goes to the site and is prompted to identify which affiliate sent him. That affiliate is connected to an organization. Up until now, all organizations use the same product list, but now some organizations would like to sell only one product: pens. (Other organizations should not sell pens, only the old product list.)

Almost all of this is complete: I have a database table for all the organizations with several attributes of each (whether products are shipped to the organization or to the buyers' homes, who the contact person is for each organization, etc.) especially whether they're doing the "pens" sale. I'm trying to figure out how to filter the product list at run time only to show pens if the user has identified an affiliate who is part of an organization that is only selling pens.

Based on my reading online, maybe `pre_get_posts` is the right extension point, but I can't figure out exactly what to do there. That function is called maybe 20 times when the page renders, and I can't figure out how to identify the call that gets products. Even if I did know which call is the one that fetches products, I'm not sure how to adjust the query to exclude everything but "pens" (or exclude "pens" depending on which organization's sale is being consulted).

I've also looked into `posts_where`, which maybe seems more hopeful, but again, I'm not sure how to decide which call is the one in which I'm interested. I tried the following:

```php
function posts_where_filter($where, $query) {
  $where = $where . " wp_posts.id = '4545'";
  error_log("Returning " . $where);
}
```

I see my added bit at the end of `$where`, but I'm mangling lots of queries, so of course my site is broken and doesn't show any items.

If `posts_where` is the correct extension point, how do I tell which "where" clause to modify? If `posts_where` is not right, what is the correct extension point and the correct way to use it?

Comment: Inside `pre_get_posts`, checking for `isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'product'` should help you identify the query that fetches the products.

Comment: _'I'm not sure how to adjust the query to exclude everything but "pens"'_ - where do you have the info, which organization is currently selected, stored? And what exactly identifies a product as a pen?

Comment: At this point, I would be happy simply being able to filter out everything but "pens" where "pens" is any product with id `4545` (`where wp_posts.id = '4732'`). From that proof of concept, I'm confident I can work out the details. To answer your question: the current affiliate is stored in a cookie by the woocommerce affiliate plugin and the affiliate-to-organization mapping is stored in the `wp_usermeta` table. The organization table is created and maintained by the plugin: it contains whether the organization is currently in a "pens-only" sale.

Comment: Using those `query_vars` conditions, I see a query that might work! I did this: `$query->set("post_id", "4732");` but it doesn't appear to have any effect. It is running (a log statement prints in the `if` statement), but for instance, `error_log(var_export($query, true));` only shows `array ('post_type' => 'product')` (no evidence of my `set` call. How do I modify the query from here? Thank you!

Comment: Should be just `p`, not `post_id`? At least that's what https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters lists.